# TypeError when using a callback in Dash

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash

I've seen more than a few other questions on the topic of callbacks not working, but mine has a slightly different twist to it.

The twist is that when I started coding the dashboard I decided to make it into a class, because the way it will be used will require creating instances of it with different data or specific parameters. This has caused me a bit of grief already, but I'm not sure how to do it differently.

Anyway, now the current issue is that I have a plot that I need to update based on the value of a slider. The plot itself originally is created in this method:

```
    def _create_plan_view(self, rl: int, component: str, thickness=20):
        plan_data = self.data.loc[(self.data.zcentre <= rl) &
                                  (self.data.zcentre >= rl-thickness), :]
        plan = px.scatter(plan_data, x='xcentre', y='ycentre', color=component,
                          color_continuous_scale='turbo')

        plan.update_layout(
            autosize=False,
            width=1200,
            height=1000,
            plot_bgcolor='#383838',
            paper_bgcolor='#383838',
            font_color='#ffffff')
        return plan
```

And here is the app layout code for both the slider and the plot:

```
            html.Div(children=[
                html.Div(children=[
                    dcc.Slider(
                        id='elevation_slider',
                        min=self.data.zcentre.min(),
                        max=self.data.zcentre.max(),
                        step=(self.data.zcentre.max() - self.data.zcentre.min()) / 100,
                        value=0,
                        marks={val: f'{val}' for val in range(self.data.zcentre.min(), self.data.zcentre.max(), 100)},
                        className='two columns offset-by-one',
                        vertical=True,
                        verticalHeight=900
                    )
                ]),
                html.Div(children=[
                    dcc.Graph(id='plan_view',
                              figure=self._create_plan_view(rl=400, component='foo'))],
                         className='nine columns'
                )]),
```

Now to update it I simply want to get the current value of slider and run the `self._create_plan_view()` method with a different parameter:

```
    @app.callback(
        Output('plan_view', 'figure'),
        Input('elevation_slider', 'value')
    )
    def _update_plan_view_for_elevation(self, elevation):
        fig = self._create_plan_view(rl=elevation, component='foo')
        return fig
```

But this only results in Dash constantly throwing errors: `TypeError: _update_plan_view_for_elevation() missing 1 required positional argument: 'elevation'`.

I'm not sure how to debug callbacks, but what I feel *might* be happening is that the actual value of the slider is getting assigned to `self` and then `elevation` is left without a value.

Could that be the case? I tried to pass `self` as one of the inputs, but this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure how to debug callbacks, but what I feel might be happening is that the actual value of the slider is getting assigned to self and then elevation is left without a value...

Yes that is what is happening

You could create a method that initializes your callbacks so the callbacks themselves don't have to take `self` as an argument:

```
def init_callbacks(self):
    @app.callback(Output("plan_view", "figure"), Input("elevation_slider", "value"))
    def _update_plan_view_for_elevation(elevation):
        fig = self._create_plan_view(rl=elevation, component="foo")
        return fig
```

`_update_plan_view_for_elevation` has access to `self` from its outer scope `init_callbacks`. Now you could call `self.init_callbacks()` in your class's `__init__` function or somewhere else after your layout has been set.